# What is the common practice for encrypting string in cookie?

Tags: cookies, encryption

I don't know which encrypt algorithms to choose, hash function can not generate the following encrypted string, any help?

```
NzQyOWRmMGY0MGVjNDc5YjQyYzcyYTQ0MmRmYTliN2ExNTQwZjI3YnsidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJKaV
9MdW8iLCJfY3JlYXRlZCI6IjIwMTIxMTAyMTE0MjIxIn0=
```

UPDATE: I just want to encrypt something in cookie, sorry for forgot the context

Comment: Please provide any background you have. Just asking us to generate a random string is "not a real question".

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting we should hack your wife's account or something similar? I'm flagging this.

Comment: Mod: removed decoding of string, contained name XXX with last name Luo.

Comment: @owlstead I just want to encrypt something in cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

beaware: encryption and encoding are 2 different things...

what you posted is a string in base64 encoding which means, once you put that into a base64 decoder, you will get the original string back ... not suitable to keep something secret

if you want just that, [here is something for you to read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) ...

if you want to store some secret, you should think about using some cypher like AES (you can store the binary cyphertext in base64 encoding if you want...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer，I will find more about the ecryption and encoding